# RequireJS error: Timeout

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jasmine

I am testing a JavaScript project with Jasmine. Everything went well but suddenly nothing works anymore although I cannot remember to have changed anything. I get this error:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

The error occurs in this piece of code:

```
describe("DesktopRouter", function(){

    var router;

    beforeAll(function(done){
        alert("1");
        require(['jquery', 'backbone', '../../../public/js/app/routers/DesktopRouter'],
            function($, Backbone, DesktopRouter) {
                alert("2");
                router = DesktopRouter;
                done();
            }
        );
    });
...
```

I can see the alert showing "1" but not the second one that should show "2". Instead nothing happens for a few seconds and then all specs return "failed" because router is undefined. I already tried to run it in Chrome, Firefox, Opera. I have an earlier version of this project that used to work. I added this version to my project again but it also didn't work any more. What could be wrong there?

This is my HTML Code. Maybe I did something wrong here, as requirejs is running asynchronously.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.2.0</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.css">

    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/boot.js"></script>

    <!-- auxillary variable -->
    <script>
        TEST = false;
    </script>

    <!-- libs -->
    <script src="../../node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <script src="../../public/js/app/config/config.js"></script>

    <!-- add spec files here -->
    <script src="spec/ToastSpec.js"></script>
    <script src="spec/DesktopRouterSpec.js"></script>
    <script src="spec/AddVehicleViewSpec.js"></script>
    <script src="spec/BaseCollectionSpec.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The Firebug console displays some errors:

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
```

occurs several times. And this one exists once:

```
Error: Load timeout for modules: text!templates/navbar.html_unnormalized3,text!templates/footer.html_unnormalized5,text!templates/blockbrowser.html_unnormalized7,text!templates/login.html_unnormalized9,text!templates/sidebar.html_unnormalized11,text!templates/vehiclesidebar.html_unnormalized13,text!templates/companies.html_unnormalized15,text!templates/companies/companiesDeleteModal.html_unnormalized16,text!templates/companies/companiesAddModal.html_unnormalized17,text!templates/dashboard.html_unnormalized19,text!templates/main_grouped_vehiclelist.html_unnormalized20,text!templates/main_errorlist.html_unnormalized21,text!templates/main_servicelist_details.html_unnormalized22,text!templates/dashboard/dashboardMessageModal.html_unnormalized23,text!templates/dashboard/dashboardDoneModal.html_unnormalized24,text!templates/workshops.html_unnormalized26,text!templates/workshops/workshopsDeleteModal.html_unnormalized27,text!templates/workshops/workshopsAddModal.html_unnormalized28,text!templates/vehicles.html_unnormalized30,text!templates/vehiclesMessageModal.html_unnormalized31,text!templates/vehiclesDeleteModal.html_unnormalized32,text!templates/users.html_unnormalized34,text!templates/usersDeleteModal.html_unnormalized35,text!templates/vehicletrips.html_unnormalized37,text!templates/infowindow/obdinfowindow.html_unnormalized38,text!templates/infowindow/tripsummarylegend.html_unnormalized39,text!templates/infowindow/tripsummarycontent.html_unnormalized40,text!templates/infowindow/tripVehiclestatuslegend.html_unnormalized41,text!templates/infowindow/tripVehiclestatuscontent.html_unnormalized42,text!templates/addvehicle.html_unnormalized46,text!templates/addvehicle/addVehicleConflictModal.html_unnormalized47,text!templates/inBox.html_unnormalized49,text!templates/vehiclesMessageModal.html_unnormalized50,text!templates/vehiclesDeleteModal.html_unnormalized51,text!templates/vehicleerrors.html_unnormalized53,text!templates/vehicledetails/errors/errorSingleTable.html_unnormalized54,text!templates/vehicledata.html_unnormalized56,text!templates/vehicledetails/data/vehicledata.html_unnormalized57,text!templates/vehicledetails/data/vehicleadditionaldata.html_unnormalized58,text!templates/vehicledetails/data/vehiclemileage.html_unnormalized59,text!templates/vehicledetails/data/changeDongleModal.html_unnormalized60,text!templates/vehicledetails/data/dropDongleModal.html_unnormalized61,text!templates/vehicledetails/data/ECDModal.html_unnormalized62,text!templates/addvehicle/addVehicleConflictModal.html_unnormalized63,text!templates/vehicleservice.html_unnormalized65,text!templates/vehicledetails/service/levelTwoserviceinformation.html_unnormalized66,text!templates/vehicledetails/service/nextservice.html_unnormalized67,text!templates/vehicledetails/service/servicereminders.html_unnormalized68,text!templates/dashboard/dashboardMessageModal.html_unnormalized69,text!templates/dashboard/dashboardDoneModal.html_unnormalized70,text!templates/adduser.html_unnormalized72,text!templates/edituser.html_unnormalized74,text!templates/edituserForm.html_unnormalized75,text!templates/editprofile.html_unnormalized77,text!templates/appdownload.html_unnormalized79,text!templates/navbar.html,text!templates/companies/companytable.html,text!templates/main_servicelist.html,text!templates/workshops/workshoptable.html,text!templates/vehicles/vehicletable.html,text!templates/users/usertable.html,text!templates/vehicledetails/trips/tripstable.html,text!templates/messages/messagestable.html,text!templates/vehicledetails/errors/errortable.html,text!templates/error.html,text!templates/enginecode.html,text!templates/vehicledetails/data/vehicleAdditionalDataUpcomingServices.html,text!templates/addvehicle.html
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
```

Comment: Does the file 'DesktopRouter' exists? It might be better to use absolute path instead of relative.

Comment: yes, it exists. i am testing four files. one of them is working properly. but I have not changed anything concerning the project structure.

Comment: Check your browser console for 404 errors?

Comment: I added the errors from the firebug console above but they don't mean a thing to me

Comment: I know this is way late, but I believe the RequireJS text plugin helps with this issue by letting RequireJS know how to read in HTML files: https://github.com/requirejs/text